# LED light and Lollipop update

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5

My LED light will not work now with the most recent update how can i fix this? I'm also having issues with my phone telling me when i have a text ( where before i would get my notification at the top of my phone ( i use Textra) now i'm not notified unless i have the notification set for my locked screen but i hate that. i don't want a bunch of notification on my locked screen.  I have the Samsung Galaxy S5

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly I had this problem as well... no matter what I had done about it I was having problems with it. In the end I took out my SD card and did a factory restore. It fixed my problem and it might be what you have to do to fix yours. I recommend taking out the SD card if you have one because I tried with it in and even factory restoring didnt work for some reason.

hope this helps!